# How to set the right div as height as the left img

Tags: html, css

So I have a image one the left side and a paragraph on the right side.

The paragraph is not as height as the image on the left side,but I want to set the height of the paragraph according to the image.

How can I do that?

Comment: what is a more realistic question is to dynamically set the height of the picture based on that of the paragraph.

Comment: I kind of have a fixed height image but sometime there is no image at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if both elements are in the same container then set **height: 100%** for paragraph

Comment: hmmm, then try with jquery: `$('p_selector').height($('img_selector').height());`

Comment: it's causing a bug,sometimes the border-bottom goes over at the top of the paragraph.And if there is no image on the left side,the paragraph still appears to be the same height as those that have a image.

Comment: Yes,but it can only be accomplished by js??

Comment: put an html example and maybe I can found a way with only css

Comment: http://gizmodo.com/  kind of like this,I am learning to do the same-like theme as this one.see when there is no img on the left side,the height of the paragraph is not fixed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32447/discussion-between-aguardientico-and-joshua-l)